# Built-in card reader in MacBook Pro doesn't work

Tags: parallels-desktop, mount, automount, sd-card

As the title says, the built-in card reader in my MacBook Pro doesn't work. It simply doesn't do anything when I instert an SD card. I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.8.

I guess one of the issues might be Parallels. I have it installed, but it's not running. In the properties of Parallels I've set that all USB devices should be loaded in Mac.

Comment: Why should the built-in camera do something when you insert an SD-card?

Comment: i'm too tired, I made a very stupid mistake. It's the card reader, not the camera.

Comment: I assume "doesn't do anything" means that the inserted card does not show up in Finder. Did you try to reboot and insert a card *before* starting Parallels? Can you see the card at least in DiskUtil?

Comment: I do **not** have Parallels started. Yes, I tried restarting. And no, it doesn't show it in Disk Utility.

Comment: Plug in th card. Open Terminal and enter `diskutil list`. What's the output?

Comment: Try a different SD Card.  I have seen this issue and it has been a problem with the card.  After using a second card, I was then able to get the reader to read the first "failed" card.

Comment: @cksum This is the output: /dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            249.7 GB   disk0s2

Comment: @TheWellington I don't have another card :(

Comment: Does the card work? Have you tried it in anything else? Like a camera or another computer?

Comment: @cksum  
It works in my camera.

Comment: Then plug it into your camera and format it. Try connecting to your Mac again. If that doesn't work, next step is to try it on another computer. If that works, the following step is to get another card and try it on your Mac. If that card doesn't work, it's likely a hardware fault and your internal card reader is not functioning properly. Trip to Apple.